# Get pull requests for private github repository via API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to programmatically get a list of open pull requests for a specific private github repository - ours, as it turns out.  I *assume* I can only do this via the github api (http://developer.github.com/) - feel free to tell me there's another way - but I can't figure out whether the API allows this, either.  The given API calls seem to assume the target repository is public, which ours is not.  I would have thought there would be a way to authenticate as a user of the given repository via ssh key (the same way committing works), but I don't see anything to that effect.  All in all I'm puzzled and not at all sure I can actually do this.  Am I missing a crucial part of the documentation, or is there possibly some alternative I can leverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [GitHub Pull Requests API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) supports private repos also. You just need to authenticate or you will get an error saying that the repository does not exist.

Example using curl and basic authentication:

```
curl -u "username" https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/pulls
```

This will then prompt you for your password and return a list of pull requests as described in the API docs.

Also check out the docs on authentication: http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: Yep, after a good while of experimentation I figured out how to pass an auth token via an HTTP header.  Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is wondering this is done using an access token. The access token is generated at https://github.com/settings/tokens and then is passed in as the access_token parameter. eg https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/pulls?access_token=:access_token