# How to get GitHub pull requests for an organization repo via the v3 API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api

I can't seem to get the pull requests for my organization's private repository using the API. I've gotten myself an OAuth2 access token which works fine. For example, this call works and returns valid JSON (`apaidnerd` would be my username and `blog` would be a public repo):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/apaidnerd/blog/pulls?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

But this URL (`myorg` is the organization name and `secretrepo` is a private repo):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/secretrepo/pulls?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Returns:

```
{ "message": "Not Found" }
```

Update: The second URL works if I try `curl -u apaidnerd http://...` from the command line. Must be a problem with my OAuth token...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: I didn't request the [repo scope](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes), which grants access to private repositories.

Comment: Do you have a running example? Having the same problem and would love to have your solution to be quicker. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh I just missed the rights for my access token http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997638/get-pull-requests-for-private-github-repository-via-api